# PostgreSQL ALL(A) <@ ANY(B)

Tags: sql, postgresql

The objective is to solve the following use case:

- table contains many numrange[] fields. Let A be one of those fields
- we need to request rows with a parameter of type numrange[] = B according to this rule : ALL(A) <@ ANY(B)

A sample of a request on table dt.t with B = {[1,3],[9,10]} would be :

```
select * from dt.t where ALL(A) <@ ANY(ARRAY[numrange(1,3),numrange(9,10)])
```

So it seems feasible. But the ALL operator can only be used on the right side of the condition...
And turning it around for about a day I don't find a clue on how to solve this use case (not using functions if possible).

The real use case will be using filtering on many fields so the solution needs to be working for multiple fields in the same where clause

```
select * 
from dt.t 
where ALL(A1) <@ ANY(ARRAY[numrange(1,3),numrange(9,10)]) 
  and ALL(A2) <@ ANY(ARRAY[numrange(10,13),numrange(20,20)])
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: Row A is a numrange[]. I do need the ALL instruction or any other way to solve the query ALL(A) <@ ANY(B), A and B being numrange[]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output. You seem to have a rather confusing data design. An array of ranges seems rather strange. But the array operators `@>` doesn't need the `any` or `all` operators. Does `a1 <@ array[....]` do what you want?

Comment: Something like `where (select  't' = ANY (SELECT unnest A1 <@ ANY(ARRAY[numrange(1,3),numrange(9,10)]) `could do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this solution :

```
select * 
from dt.t t1 
where (
    select count(1) 
    from (
        select unnest(A) a 
        from dt.t t2 
        where t2.id=t1.id
    ) t 
    where t.a <@ ANY(ARRAY['[1,3)'::numrange])) = array_length(A,1);
```

The idea is :

- select unnest(A) a from dt.t t2 where t2.id=t1.id => gives each element of ARRAY field A
- t.a <@ ANY(ARRAY['[1,3)'::numrange]) => tests if this element is included in the parameter => <@ ANY(B) part
- (select count(1) [...]) = array_length(A,1) => checks that all elements of A is valid => the ALL(A) part of the problem

Tried it, works, and seems legit. The only thing really important is that B is the minimal union of itself (there shall be no numrange[] equivalent to B with less numrange in it).
Apart from that, seems to work. Thank you all for your help and time.